# Rodando programas feitos em Delphi 1 no windows 10

Tags: delphi

Aprendi a fazer programas simples em Delphi1, usando o quickreport1 para fazer relatórios.
Estou executando estes programas no meu XP pack 3, por alguns anos. Comprei um notebook da Acer, com o windows10 instalado. Já tentei com o modo de compatibilidade com o botão direito do mouse, mas não consegui nada. Pergunta: como faço para conseguir rodar estes programas? Tenho urgência de rodar estes programas. Me ajudem!!! Tenho que trabalhar em ambientes que não tem rede elétrica disponível, por isso tenho que trabalhar com notebooks.
Obrigado
Eliazar

Comment: vc só quer rodar os programas ou foi vc que desenvolveu eles ? quero dizer, vc tem o código fonte ?

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao Stackoverflow em Português. Você poderia ser mais especifico detalhar mais a pergunta? Você esta tendo problema no código fonte ou é só com a incompatibilidade do programa? Aqui faça um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender como o site funciona.

Comment: E eu achando que trabalhar com Deplhi 5 era ruim. Meus pêsames e boa sorte.

Comment: Caro Nelson! Boa noite!
Encontrei este site consultando o Google. Meu problema é somente de instalação.
Não penso em instalar o Delphi 1 na máquina com o windows 10, somente tentar rodar os programas que eu mesmo desenvolvi. Então não estou com problemas com o código fonte. Os programas requerem que o texto abaixo seja colocado no win.ini do windows. Fiz este programa para isso, o qual foi aceito no xp: Este programa editou ao ser rodado
no win.ini do c:\windows, o seguinte texto:
[IDAPI]
DLLPATH=C:\IDAPI
CONFIGFILE01=C:\IDAPI\IDAPI.CFG [Borland Language Drivers]
LDPath=C:\IDAPI\LANGDRV Caso q